# How to deal with anomaly detection when the data is produced via multiple resources?

Tags: time-series, anomaly-detection

I have a resources lets say $x$ and $y$. These resources produces location data with a timestamp, hence its timeseries data. The data looks like this (resource_uuid,timestamp, location).

It might be the case that resources both belong to a same class in sense of a higher abstraction(they behave same way and the data which they produce is from the same distribution), hence it might make sense to combine observations from resources which belongs to the same class.

My initial approach was to train an anomaly detection model for each resource, but this becomes quite heavy to calculate. How would you approach an anomaly detection problem when a data is produced via multiple resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to cluster the spatio-temporal data, and then learn models for the entire cluster, using all of the data from the cluster. This is described in [Bayesian Dynamic Modeling: Sharing Information Across Time and Space](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LVPikT58meg).

Another approach would be to use a model trained on all the dataset (likely with self-supervised techniques), to output a representation of the input time-series. Then learn smaller individual models on this shared representation. There are many options for both representation model and anomaly detection model, an illustrative example could be [SMATE: Semi-Supervised Spatio-Temporal Representation Learning on Multivariate Time Series](https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.00578), and then using something like Gaussian Mixture Model or Isolation Forest on the embedding vector for the anomaly detector.

There is however not any guarantee that this will be faster than making individual models, as it is the same amount of data to be processed. But in practice there might be batching benefits, or it becomes possible to sub-samples the data in the clusters.

Comment: can you give a material for your 2nd suggestion?

Comment: I added an example now

Comment: So roughly the idea in the 1st approach is to have a some cluster algorithm $A$, then $B = A(D)$ is a collection of clusters where $D$ is the dataset. Then let $C_i \in B$ be a collection of points which belong to the $i$th cluster. Then we just simply $P_i(C_i) = R_i$ where $P_i$ be an anomaly detector for $i$th cluster and $R_i$ is a collection of anomalies. Is this thought correct?